# Running CMD as admin to uninstall driver

Tags: batch-file, cmd, driver

I am trying to run an uninstall command for several remote computers. Is there a way to run CMD as admin to run a script that uninstalls the driver I need it to?

I was using PSEXEC and i can connect to all the computers but I it won't run the batch file i have to uninstall the driver as admin.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by pressing `windows key` `x` and selecting open command prompt as administrator

Comment: I have to hold shift then right click "run as different user" then put company admin credentials in. The option above does not work. Is there a way to use psexec to open cmd as administrator (username and password hard coded in the script) and it runs the command?

Comment: @swstrau118 sorry, misread the question, will delete my answer